# ¿Como puedo mostrar la linea de identacion en Vim? (si uso dos espacios)

Tags: vim

Quiero saber como puedo ver las lineas en vertical que indican el nivel de identacion de las instrucciones, como las que muestro a continuacion (son las lineas debajo de los if):

```
if(variable_boolean){
|  instrucciones
|  instrucciones
|  
|  if(variable_boolean){
|  | instrucciones
|  | instrucciones
|  }
}
```

Dentro de mi archivo .vimrc tengo las siguientes configuraciones con relacion a la identación

```
"Una tabulacion vale 2 espacios"
set tabstop=2

"Cuando idento con shift y '>', usa 2 espacios"
set shiftwidth=2

"Cuando precione tabulador se expande a espacios"
set expandtab
```

Eh estado indagando un poco en internet y no encontre un metodo para mostrar el nivel de identacion en 2 espacios en concreto, debido a que, si hay información cuando **una tabulacion vale dos espacios** pero no cuando **expandes una tabulacion** a dos espacios.

La siguiente imagen es la vista previa de lo que me gustaria lograr:

[image: Imagen de la vista previa que me gustaria tener]

La siguiente imagen es la vista preiva de la configuracion de mi editor:

[image: Imagen de la vista previa de mi vim]

Nota: Es mi primera pregunta y he leído el post de "¿Como preguntar?", sin embargo, acepto críticas y/o sugerencias respecto a mi pregunta.

Comment: instala el plugin [indentLine](https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine)

Comment: Gracias y disculpa la tardanza . . .